# Change Values of DateTimePicker

Tags: asp.net, datetimepicker

I am creating a MVC application, and the user's have asked that on the `datetimepicker` if the values could be switched to intervals of `6`.

So on this part of the `datetimepicker`:

[image]

Is there a way to change the values to `00`, `06`, `12`, `18`, etc?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

The original datetimepicker was based off of this:

```
fillMinutes = function () {
            var table = widget.find('.timepicker-minutes table'),
                currentMinute = viewDate.clone().startOf('h'),
                html = [],
                row = $('<tr>'),
                step = options.stepping === 1 ? 5 : options.stepping;

            while (viewDate.isSame(currentMinute, 'h')) {
                if (currentMinute.minute() % (step * 4) === 0) {
                    row = $('<tr>');
                    html.push(row);
                }
                row.append('<td data-action="selectMinute" class="minute' + (!isValid(currentMinute, 'm') ? ' disabled' : '') + '">' + currentMinute.format('mm') + '</td>');
                currentMinute.add(step, 'm');
            }
            table.empty().append(html);
        },
```

so I changed the `step = options.stepping === 1 ? 5 : options.stepping;` to:

`step = options.stepping === 1 ? 6 : options.stepping;`